# Finding values $a$ and $b$ so that $G(x)$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

[image]

I calculated the limit of the function from the negative and positive sides of $2$ and $4$, set the left and right-handed limits equal, and obtained the following equations:

$3a -6b + 3 = 0$ as $x$ approaches $2$ and

$28b + a -11 = 0$ as $x$ approaches $4$

However, when I use systems of equations to solve for a or b, the values do not make the functions continuous. I get $b = \frac{36}{90}$ and $a = \frac15$.

I'm not sure what to do from here. Is my approach correct or do I need to use another method?

Comment: Your approach is correct, it looks like you simply made a mistake solving the system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is correct and even the system of equations you found is correct, but you can quickly check that $b = \frac{36}{90}, a=\frac{1}{5}$ is not a solution to the system of equations you gave.
You can plug those values in to see that $3\cdot\frac{1}{5} -6\cdot\frac{36}{96} + 3 =  \frac{27}{20}$ which is no good.

As a sanity check, this is where i might go to wolframalpha.com and type something like "solve 3a−6b+3=0, 28b+a−11=0", which indeed returns the solution to the problem.

Note that the first equation says $a = 2b-1$.  Substituting in the second equation gives $30b - 12 = 0$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying